# Importing a file based upon the path

Tags: python

I have a python script that exports a file using the following command in a function. It's works, but I need to import that file after exporting and loop through it.

```
connector.save_csv(path,'_'+"GT_Weekly"+'_'+keys)
```

Thereore, I've been hard coding the file name and using it with open(). However, I was wondering how I could specify the file name in the same way as specified when I saved it.

Here's the hard coded approach:

```
with open(path,'_'+"GT_Weekly"+'_'+keys+'.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = []
```

I want to take the save_csv arguments and add it to open but that doesn't work. How can I do this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Both keys and path were specified as

```
keys ="football"

path = "/home/abraham/Trends"
```

What component needs to be changed to an integer? It's not evident to me

Furthermore, when I add int,I get the following error

```
with int(open(path,'_'+"GT_Weekly"+'_'+keys+'.csv', 'rt')) as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = []

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
>>>
```

Comment: *"that doesn't work"* - *what* doesn't work? You haven't actually shown that code! Does `connector.save_csv` add anything to the path and filename (e.g. `'.csv'`, by the looks of it)?

Comment: Are you sure those two are correct? From your save function, filename should be `something_GT_Weekly_something.csv`, but the file you are opening is `TrendsGT_Daily.csv`?

Comment: How that "doesn't work"? You got an error mesasge? The file names in your code are not equal.

Comment: I just edited, it doesn't work when I place the same structure when I export the file.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) accepts a path, a file name, and a mode; but it doesn't.  The parameters are a file name, a mode, and a buffer size.  The buffer size should be an integer, but you are passing `'rt'`; hence, you get an error message.

I guess you want `open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rt')` instead, or possibly `open(path + filename, 'rt')`, if the last component of `path` is a prefix part of the filename you want, not a directory name.